# How to copy stats of a table in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008R2.

I have a table `A` which has bunch of indexes and have stats on those indexes. There are no triggers on table `A`.

I want to have a new table `B` which is an exact copy of table `A`. Which means table definition, indexes, stats and data are exactly same in both tables.

So when I query on `A` or `B` the results are same.

And when I query on `sys.indexes`, `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats`, `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` and `sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats` for `A` or `B` the results are same.

I mean `object_id` column would obviously be different but I want:

- columns like `avg_fragmentation_in_percent` etc. in `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` are same
- columns like `user_seeks` etc. in `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` are same
- columns like `leaf_insert_count` etc. in `sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats` are same.

I can script out the table definition and its indexes of table `A` and then rename them for table `B`.

But how to script out the stats of table `A` and copy them for table `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell:

```
pushd;
import-module sqlps -disablenamechecking;
popd;

$opts = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.ScriptingOptions;
$opts.OptimizerData = $true;

$server = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server '.';
$database = $server.Databases['AdventureWorks2014'];
$table = $database.tables | where {$_.schema -eq 'Person' -and $_.name -eq 'Person'}


foreach ($stat in $table.Statistics) {
    $stat.Script($opts);
}
```

Answer (score -6):

use cntrl A then cntrl C; then cntrl V done hence copied all of it